# Using read.csv.ffdf() throws an error

Tags: r, bigdata

I'm trying to read in a large (3.7 million rows, 180 columns) dataset into R, using the `ff` package. There are several data types in the dataset - factor, logical, and numeric.

The problem is when reading in numeric variables. For example, one of my columns is:

```
TotalBeforeTax
126.9
88.0
124.5
90.9
...
```

When I try reading the data in, the following error is thrown:

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  scan() expected 'a real', got '"126.90000"'
```

I tried declaring the class to `integer` (it's already declared as `numeric`) using the `colClasses` argument, but to no avail. I also tried changing it to `a real` (whatever that is supposed to mean), and it starts reading in the data, but at some point throws:

```
Error in methods::as(data[[i]], colClasses[i]) : 
  no method or default for coercing “character” to “a real”
```

(My guess is, because it comes across an `NA` and doesn't know what to do with it.)

The funny thing is, if I declare the column as a `factor`, everything reads in nicely.

What gives?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22357396/ff-in-r-no-applicable-method-for-recodelevels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so I managed to solve this using a primitive workaround. First, split the .csv file using a csv file splitter application. Then, execute the following code:

```
## First, set the folder where the split .csv files are. Set the file names.

sourceDir <- "split_files_folder"
sourceFile <- paste(sourceDir,"common_name_of_split_files", sep = "/")

## Now set the number of split pieces.

pieces <- "some_number"

## Set the destination folder for the tab-delimited text files. 
## Set the output file name.

destDir <- "destination_folder"
destFile <- paste(paste(destDir, "datafile", sep = "/"), "txt", sep = ".")

## Now, initialize the loop.

for (i in 1:pieces)
{
  temp <- read.csv(file = paste(paste(sourceFile, i, sep = "_"), "csv", sep = "."))
  if (i == 1) 
  {
    write.table(temp, file = destFile, quote = FALSE, sep = "\t", row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE)
  }
  else 
  {
    write.table(temp, file = destFile, append = TRUE, quote = FALSE, sep = "\t", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
  }
}
```

And voila! You've got a huge tab-delimited text file!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @neuron. To improve the speed of the loop, I would suggest using fread() from data.table package, instead of read.csv . The function fread probably the fastest method to read a dataset, as shown by these benchmarks https://rpubs.com/dpastoor/benchmark-nm-read and

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

You could try `laf_to_ffdf` from the `ffbase` package. Something like:

```
library(LaF)
library(ffbase)

con <- laf_open_csv("yourcsvfile.csv", 
  column_names = [as character vector with column names], 
  column_types = [a character vector with colClasses], 
  dec=".", sep=",", skip=1)

ffdf <- laf_to_ffdf(con)
```

Or if you want to detect the types automatically:

```
library(LaF)
library(ffbase)

m <- detect_dm_csv("yourcsvfile.csv")
con <- laf_open(m)
ffdf <- laf_to_ffdf(con)
```

**Solution 2**

Use a column class of `character` for the offending column and cast the column to numeric in `transFUN` argument of `read.csv.ffdf`:

```
ffdf <- read.csv.ffdf([your regular arguments], transFUN = function(d) {
  d$offendingcolumn <- as.numeric(d$offendingcolumn)
  d
})
```

Comment: I tried solution 2. Unfortunately, the read function doesn't support characters (you can check with `.vimplemented`), and throws an error. I tried loading them as factors and converting them back with `transFUN` to numerics, but that gives the wrong values.

Comment: So, I managed to solve it using a primitive workaround. I used a csv splitter application to break up the file into manageable chunks of 50,000 rows each. Then I wrote an R script that would load a chunk, and then export it as a tab-delimited text file, than load the next chunk, export it and appen the output to the already generated text file, and so on. The `read.delim.ffdf` function didn't cause any issues when loading numerical or integer values.

Comment: @ssantic Too bad the second solution didn't work. That has probably to do with the fact that `read.csv.ffdf` doesn't like it when the colClasses change. And the first (possible) solution?

Comment: @ssantic If you have a working solution, I would add it as an answer.

Comment: Honestly, the first one took forever to load the file (and there is no `VERBOSE` argument, so I stopped it at some point). I'll post my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the number 126.9000 being surrounded by a quote ".
So maybe you should first get the variable as character and secondly remove all unwanted character, and finally convert the variable to numeric.

Comment: I thought that as well, but when I use the plain `read.csv` function to read in, say, the first several thousand lines, it works like a charm. Plus, I'm not sure I can change the types of columns in an `ff` data frame the same way I can in a regular one.

Comment: @ssantic There was a discussion on this problem some time ago on the r-devel list: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2013-September/067605.html. Not that a solution is given there...